# Method unrelated to an object

Tags: c++

I have a basic question about OOP. I would like to create a method inside the class which uses 2 objects of this class as arguments and returns a float value based on the attributes of these objects.

```
public float MyMethod(CMyClass obj1, CMyclass obj2)
```

When I want to use this method in main() I cannot do it like this:

```
CMyClass o1 = CMyClass();
CMyClass o2 = CMyClass();
float x = MyMethod(o1, o2);
```

I cannot see this method because it is related to an object. I can access it like this:

```
o1.MyMethod(...)
```

but this does not make sense.

Comment: You do know that, unlike Java, a C++ function doesn't *have* to be a member of a class?

Comment: `public float MyMethod(CMyClass obj1, CMyclass obj2)` this is a syntax error in C++.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the method `static`, and access it like `MyClass::MyMethod`

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static void MyMethod(const MyClass & arg1, const MyClass & arg2) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to access attribute of those, use a friend function(non member). You can declare it in you class:

```
friend float MyMethod(CMyClass obj1, CMyclass obj2);
```

Comment: You can also use static as other said, but 'static' keyword has been abused, don't use static all the time! For things like operator overloading, friend or free function is better.

Answer (score 1):

you want

```
static float MyMethod(CMyClass obj1, CMyclass obj2)
```

`static` keyword here will make the method belong to the class, not an individual instance of the class/object.  Access as `CMyClass::MyMethod`.

Comment: unlike in Java, in C++ public is not modifier for a method